# Why is my SwitchCompat OnCheckedChangeListener firing on creation and how can I stop it?

Tags: android

I've got a fragment in my android app using a androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat component. In my onViewCreated function I set a OnCheckedChangeListener with the following code

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checked ->
    presenter.onSwitchChanged(checked)
        }
```

When I test my code it not only sets the listener, it fires it. So the act of creating the listener kicks off my network API, etc.  Is this a bug?  How can I stop this from happening?  I want the listener to fire only when the user interacts with the switch.

Comment: Maybe other place change the mySwitch state.Please show the whole file.

Comment: do you have a call to `mySwitch.setChecked()` inside the `onViewCreated`? This will also trigger the listener.